# Batch script to replace parentheses

Tags: batch-file, window

I have a .txt document with over 32,000 lines of commented machine code. It looks like this:

```
; Display menu window
C0/000E:    E220        SEP #$20       (Set 8-bit accumulator)
C0/0010:    C210        REP #$10       (Set 16-bit X and Y)
```

I need to convert the comments as follows for compiling purposes:

```
; Display menu window
C0/000E:    E220        SEP #$20       ; Set 8-bit accumulator
C0/0010:    C210        REP #$10       ; Set 16-bit X and Y
```

Specifically, that means:

- If the line does not start with "C0/", do nothing.
- If the 34th character is not an opening parenthesis, the line probably just contains data, so do nothing.
- If it is an opening parenthesis, replace it with a semi-colon and a whitespace
- Then, find and delete the closing parenthesis. Preferably, it should give up if none is found on the same line, but this shouldn't be necessary.

Note that this board replaces tabs with a number of spaces, so the opening parenthesis won't appear to be the 34th character to you.

Ideally, I'd like a Batch script that allows me to drag-and-drop a document (e.g., abc.txt), and automatically get a different file (e.g., abc2.txt). But that's not mandatory.

Edit: It has to be stressed that the code itself can contain parentheses, so a simple find-and-replace is not an option. Example:

```
C0/0000:    7C0600      JMP ($0006,X)  (Display window X)
```

Comment: Would it be enough to remove any `)` and replace `(` with `; ` (with space)? Why is it necessary to check for `C0/` at the beginning and for `(` as 34th char? It's easy to write such a script but it's even easier if my suggestion is valide.

Comment: Unfortunately, that wouldn't work. If you look at the code I provided, you can see there is a function title. Also, as I said, some lines don't have a parenthesis as the 34th character. Another issue is that the code itself can feature parentheses.

Comment: Still don't get it. However, code comming in some minutes ;-)

Comment: I've added an example at the end of my original post. It shows code that contains parentheses. These can't be removed. "JMP ($0006,X)" must remain as such.

Comment: Done. This works for me if I replace 34 with 39. If you are sure that 34 is correct, the code should work for you. otherwise you will have to play around with the char positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is about extracting the file dropped to your bat, generating the output name and clering the target file.

In the second part of the code we are checking for your criteria one by one and performing the replacement only if all of them fit to the current line.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET source=%1

FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%t IN ("%source%") DO SET target=%%t
SET target=!target!2.txt
TYPE NUL>!target!

FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=]" %%j in ('type "%source%" ^| find /V /N ""') DO (
    IF "%%k"=="" (
        ECHO.>>!target!
    ) ELSE (
        SET currentLine=%%k
        IF "!currentLine:~0,2!"=="C0" (
            IF "!currentLine:~34,1!"=="(" (
                SET left=!currentLine:~0,33!
                SET right=!currentLine:~34!
                ECHO !right!
                SET right=!right:(=; !
                SET right=!right:^)=!
                ECHO !right!
                SET currentLine=!left!!right!
            )
        )
        ECHO !currentline!>>!target!
    )
)
```

As you've mentioned there might be a problem interpreting tabs and spaces. In my case (I've copied your input file from your post) I had to use this:

```
...
IF "!currentLine:~39,1!"=="(" (
    SET left=!currentLine:~0,38!
    SET right=!currentLine:~39!
...
```

Comment: Thanks. It would work perfectly if it weren't for the following two problems: 1. The script deletes blank lines, 2. It also deletes lines that start with a semi-colon.

Comment: It seems like the script will generate a blank file if executed from a USB drive. Any idea why this happens? It would be nice if this worked regardless of drive.

Comment: Could be a path problem. Try to move the bat to the USB and try again. If it works then try to use absolute paths.

Comment: Hmm. Apparently, it can't find the path if there's any space in it. So it's not drive-specific, but folder name-specific.

Comment: In that case simply surround `%source%` and `!target!` with quotes if not done already.